# SonicWALL Site-to-Site Subnet Not Lighting Up

Tags: vpn, subnet, sonicwall

I hope someone out there can help me since SonicWALL support is horrible; three days, and still no response back from them.

I have two NSA 3600 SonicWALLs, one at each of two different sites.

I have introduced more subnets on each network, and I added them to the group associated with the current site-to-site VPN tunnel that is working, but the connections will not light up green; only the original one stays green.

Here is the current setup:

```
Site 1 VPN Setup:
  Local Networks 
    --- Selected Group: Site 1 Local Networks 
    ---- Group Members: 192.168.214.0/255.255.255.0
                        192.168.240.0/255.255.254.0
  Remote Networks 
    --- Selected Group: Site 2 Local Networks
    ---- Group Members: 192.168.202.0/255.255.255.0
                        192.168.198.0/255.255.255.0
                        192.168.114.0/255.255.255.0

Site 2 VPN Setup:
  Local Networks
    --- Selected Group: Site 2 Local Networks
    ---- Group Members: 192.168.202.0/255.255.255.0
                        192.168.198.0/255.255.255.0
                        192.168.114.0/255.255.255.0
  Remote Networks
    --- Selected Group: Site 1 Local Networks
    ---- Group Members: 192.168.214.0/255.255.255.0
                        192.168.240.0/255.255.254.0
```

Everything looks good to me but the only subnet which turn green are as follows, these of which were already working before adding more subnets:

```
Site 1: 192.168.202.0
Site 2: 192.168.240.0
```

The only thing I did on both SonicWALLs was edit the groups that were already configured for the 192.168.202.0 and 192.168.240.0, and add in my other subnets that are required.

If anyone has any insight into this, that would be great.

EDIT:

Strange. I enabled Keep-Alive on the advanced tab of the policy, and it started working. I noticed my other policies have this enabled.

Comment: Can you post the logs related to VPN IKE and IPSec? Needed for both firewalls.